# Video Player for hosted videos

Tags: video

I'd like to add videos for a webpage, but I don't want to use Youtube or any other site to host them, i'd like to host them on my own server. what are some good tools availible for video players on a site?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A mix of open source/commercial and Flash/HTML5 options for hosting your own videos:

- [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/)
- [OS FLV](http://www.osflv.com/)
- [FLV Player](http://flv-player.net/)
- [f4Player](http://code.google.com/p/f4player/)
- [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)
- [Video JS](http://videojs.com/) (HTML5)
- [Sublime Video Player](http://jilion.com/sublime/video) (HTML5)

Comment: +1 on Flowplayer...have used successfully on dozens of websites.

Also have to give a plug to ffmpeg if you get into having to process, thumbnail, or just generally deal with video from others dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using your site for commercial purposes I think your best best is JW PLayer from Longtail, http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/. It is free for non-commercial purposes and easy to add and integrate with you website.

If you decide to use it on a commercial site it is still pretty in-expensive, costing less than $100 for the most simple plan.

They offer a number players to play most if not all major video types.  I used it on the last website I wrote and it was extremely easy to setup.

Comment: What differentiates JS Player from Flowplayer, Video JS, Sublime, video4all and other open source players? AFAIK, you can't embed a video codec into a Flash or JS file, so it'd be using the codecs provided by the Flash plugin and each browser's HTML5 support. So unless JW Player comes with addition browser extensions or ActiveX plugins, it would only support the standard video formats supported by all the other players.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [video4all](http://code.google.com/p/video4all/). If HTML5 is supported it uses the HTML5 tags, if not it falls back to [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/). So you have really man features you can use. On one side the HTML5 tags with all the settings and on the other side you have all the flowplayer features, likes Auto-Thumbnailing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to use jPlayer http://jplayer.org which integrates nicely with jQuery. It seems to have lots of visual CSS customizations and handles all the usual formats with Flash as a last resort. I'm not an expert yet, but it seems like it'll do the job.

I'm creating a site with a 3 to 4 videos (in different formats) and you can preview each video to

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at the [Podlove Web Player](http://podlove.github.io/podlove-web-player/), an HTML5 audio and video player.