# Host Private videos on my site or use third party video hosting

Tags: web-hosting, video, streaming

I’m working on a e-learning startup. We are going to have recorded video lectures from professors ranging from 30-45 minutes long which are going to be accessible to students once they register and pay for the course. Hence these are private videos.

1. What is the best format to save these videos in, FLV, MP4 or something else? I’m leaning towards MP4 as FLV videos won’t play on iPads and iPhones.
2. Most importantly, where do I host these video files? Should we host them on our servers or use third-party video hosting? I’m inclined towards third party because that will reduce the load on our servers and the video streaming experience would be better for users.
3. If I go for video hosting, what are my options? I can’t use YouTube because they don’t offer domain control. Vimeo does offer privacy of domain control but I don’t think I can use that for commercial purpose. Someone mentioned BitGravity but I haven’t checked that out. What options would be good for my usage?

Comment: Do any of these questions help? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/what-are-my-options-for-private-video-hosting http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1924/video-player-for-hosted-videos http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/best-way-to-deliver-hd-video-for-a-small-userbase

Comment: Thanks Nick - the 3rd link answers two of my questions. Regarding the FLV or Mp4 , does it make any difference at all - Thanks

Comment: Glad they helped. Use MPEG-4 for video compression. (More detailed answer below.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best format to save these videos in?

YouTube and Vimeo both currently recommend **H264 (MPEG-4 AVC) video compression** and AAC audio at 24, 25, or 30fps. You can find compression how-tos from [YouTube](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=165543) and from [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/help/compression).

If you are planning to serve the video yourself (instead of from a third-party service such as YouTube), you will likely have to compress and serve multiple versions of the same video in different formats, depending on what codecs the visitor's browser supports. Mark Pilgrim's ['Video on the Web'](http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html) tutorial goes into much more detail, and reading it will probably encourage you to use a third-party video hosting service who will handle the technicalities for you.

My advice with Web video is almost always to use a third-party video hosting service so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel, and so that you can spend time producing content instead of working out how to serve it.

(You say your other questions were answered in my comment above, but let me know if you need any more information.)

Comment: Thanks Nick - appreciate your input and the links you provided

Answer (score 2):

1. The codec you choose should not be a problem at all regarding web streaming, just use whatever format suits you for storing backup, high-quality copies of your videos. When you upload them to services like Youtube or Vimeo, they are converted to a format that is compatible with most browsers anyway.
2. You should definitely use a third party service if you do not want to deal with transfer limits or things like Content Delivery Networks to be sure that your videos are always available.
3. Vimeo does offer a "Pro" option, which includes commercial video hosting: http://vimeo.com/pro. I have not used it but it seems fine, especially for less than 200 dollars a year.